# How to prevent python from rounding off

Tags: python

I need to calculate log of **(1 - (1+x)^(-1))**. The problem being, one value of x in my dataset is extremely small (order of e-29). Python calculates the whole equation as zero and hence log gives a "*math domain error*". This is an important outlier for a meteorological dataset hence can't be ignored. Any help regarding this issue?

round() doesn't help.

Comment: It isn't Python that is rounding off. It is the floating-point processor in your computer, and so you will see something similar no matter what the language. @KenY-N 's suggestion may be your easiest way out of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of floating point number precision, i recommend using integral using exponent

https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html